# Creating and bootstraping a db with the initial data

Tags: android, database

I need to create a db and store some initial data into it if the database doesn't exist when my application is launched. How can I do that?

I know I should use the class `SQLiteOpenHelper` but haven't found an example which creates a dabatase  **if it doesn't exist** and bootstraps it with the initial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> haven't found an example which creates a dabatase if it doesn't exist and bootstraps it with the initial data.

Every example you have seen of `SQLiteOpenHelper` creates a database if it doesn't exist. That is half of the point of *having* `SQLiteOpenHelper` (the other half being assisting with database migrations when your schema needs to change). The actual database creation itself is handled by `SQLiteOpenHelper`. You just need to override `onCreate()` and create your schema (and, if relevant, populate tables with starter data).

So, for example, in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsROWID), I have a `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass that does just that:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.constants;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME="constants.db";
  private static final int SCHEMA=1;
  static final String TITLE="title";
  static final String VALUE="value";
  static final String TABLE="constants";

  public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE constants (title TEXT, value REAL);");

    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Death Star I");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_DEATH_STAR_I);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Earth");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Jupiter");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_JUPITER);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Mars");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_MARS);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Mercury");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_MERCURY);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Moon");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_MOON);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Neptune");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_NEPTUNE);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Pluto");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_PLUTO);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Saturn");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_SATURN);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Sun");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_SUN);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, The Island");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_THE_ISLAND);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Uranus");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_URANUS);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);

    cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Venus");
    cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_VENUS);
    db.insert(TABLE, TITLE, cv);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                        int newVersion) {
    throw new RuntimeException("How did we get here?");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

- First of all I will not use *SQLiteOpenHelper* because it is
  over-coplicated. Use instead a ORM database like [DBFlow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow). It is
  very easy to learn and to use.
- Second, I will extend the *App* class and
  place in there a code that read a shared preference value that you
  can use as a flag to determine if it is the first start of the app or
  not. Basically if the variable it's not present at all in the shared
  prefs, then you can assume that it is the first start and you can run
  a function to fill in the database. Don't forget to store in shared
  prefs this flag at this point.

In the next app run, since the flag will be present, the initialisation function will be skipped.

You can see the App class as something that is started before every activity. It's not a class required in a project, but to do those kind of initializations it's the right place where to put them.